# Сделать кнопку активной если выбран один из radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как делать кнопку активной при выборе одного из radiobutton

```html
<form action="#">
  <label class="wrap-radio-btn">
       <input type="radio" value="0" class="radio-btn no" name="smile">
       <span class="icon-smile-sad"></span>
       <span>нет</span>
  </label>
  <label class="wrap-radio-btn">
       <input type="radio" value="5" class="radio-btn yes" name="smile" >
       <span class="icon-smile"></span>
       <span>да</span>
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-main">
      <span>Следующий вопрос  >></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  $("button").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
  <label class="wrap-radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" value="0" class="radio-btn no" name="smile">
    <span class="icon-smile-sad"></span>
    <span>нет</span>
  </label>
  <label class="wrap-radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" value="5" class="radio-btn yes" name="smile" >
    <span class="icon-smile"></span>
    <span>да</span>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" class="btn-main" disabled>
    <span>Следующий вопрос  >></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, без jQuery (кстати, обратите внимание на `&gt;` вместо `>` в надписи кнопки, таким образом можно избежать различных проблем с парсингом HTML-кода):

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input name="radio-value" type="radio" onchange="updateButtonState()" value="0" checked>
      <span>нет</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input name="radio-value" type="radio" onchange="updateButtonState()" value="5">
      <span>да</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">
    <span>Следующий вопрос &gt;&gt;</span>
  </button>
  <script>
    function updateButtonState(){
      var submitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
      var selectedRadioButton = document.querySelector('input[name="radio-value"]:checked');
      submitButton.disabled = selectedRadioButton.value != '5';
    }
    updateButtonState();
  </script>
</form>
```